# Error for below code of scatter!

Tags: eosio-code, scatter

I am trying to call contract by scatter but i met with below error
Error is  **Cannot read property 'find' of undefined**

Any other way to call contract and suggestions appretiated!

```
function gets()
  {  const scatter = window.scatter

    const network = {
        blockchain: 'eos',
        host: 'http://jungle2.cryptolions.io',
        port: 80
    }


      console.log("in gets");
      scatter.getIdentity().then(identity => {
        console.log(identity, "identityFound")
        // do not assign to window in actual projects... only for learning.
        window.identity = identity

      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error, "identityCrisis!")
        // User "Deny" action

      })
      const accountt =  scatter.identity.accounts.find(x => x.blockchain === 'eos');   
      console.log(accountt); 
      // Contract calling code goes here.....
    }
```

Comment: You can also hit up the Scatter Developers channel: https://t.me/ScatterDevelopers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ami Heines suggested this can be achieve using **async** nature of js. So define your  getScatter action like this and try to define network in a config.json file like I used

```
  async getScatter(PropsValue) {
    const scatter = PropsValue.scatterObj;
    const { accounts } = await scatter.getIdentity({
      accounts: [config.EOS_CONFIG.network]
    });
    return accounts;
  }
```

try to avoid pormises.

Comment: I got it I was previously not getting an account because I was not passing network configurations as parameters now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a timing issue in your code. The javascript code is non blocking and runs in a strange order for programmers coming from a different background.

You are calling `getIdentity` above but the code keeps on running and trying to use the `scatter.identity.accounts` without waiting for the result of the call to 
`getIdentity`.

Move the line of code with the `scatter.identity.accounts.find` to right after the `identityFound` log message. This will only be executed after the process of getting the identity happens.